# Combine rank and if functions values based on total amount

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking for a formula which could do a **rank** and an **if** formula at the same time. Here is an example:
[image]

In column C, I would need what is displayed in column D, but with a formula. I have different categories with a total amount for each. The idea would be that the formula in column C would give for the three top numbers (12'203, 4'252 and 7'428) the number 3, the next three top numbers the number "2" and the last three numbers, "1". I've tried a series of **rank** and **if** functions but it's leading me nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the RANK function of your choice (I have used RANK.EQ) in the ROUNDUP function with a suitable divisor, like this:

```
=ROUNDUP(RANK.EQ($B4,$B$4:$B$12,1)/3,0)
```

[image]

Comment: great input cheers